# Multiple precompiled assemblies with the same name Newtonsoft.Json.dll included or the current platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG7Lk.png)

I know where is the problem but I don't know how to fix it, I tried to delete and rename the duplicated file but it's back as it was

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to delete one of them. How did it come back after you deleted it? Maybe you deleted one from some asset/library that had an editor script that repaired itself? Try deleting the other one.
Also it would be no harm to reboot the project after deleting one: close everything (unity visual studio etc.), delete the unity temporary folders (Libray, obj in root of your project) and open the project again.